# The logical structure of a certain proof.

Tags: logic

> Let $x,y,z$ be real numbers with $0<x<y<z<1$. Prove that at least two of the numbers $x,y,z$ are within $\frac{1}{2}$ unit from one another.

The proof I'm referring to is this

> $0<x<y\wedge y-x>\frac12\implies y>\frac12$
>
> $y<z<1\wedge z-y>\frac12\implies y<\frac12$
>
> Contradiction
>
> Therefore .......

However the statement we ought to prove has the following logical form

$$(\forall x)(\forall y)(\forall z)(0<x<y<z<1\implies([|x-y|\le\frac12\wedge|z-y|\le\frac12]\vee[|z-y|\le\frac12\wedge|x-z|\le\frac12]\vee[|x-z|\le\frac12\wedge|x-y|\le\frac12]))$$

So to prove it by contradiction one would assume $0<x<y<z<1$ and then assume the negation of the *consequent* which is $$\neg([|x-y|\le\frac12\wedge|z-y|\le\frac12]\vee[|z-y|\le\frac12\wedge|x-z|\le\frac12]\vee[|x-z|\le\frac12\wedge|x-y|\le\frac12]))\iff([|x-y|>\frac12\vee|z-y|>\frac12]\wedge[|z-y|>\frac12\vee|x-z|>\frac12]\wedge[|x-z|>\frac12\vee|x-y|>\frac12]))$$

So to prove it wrong we all need to take just one piece (because of the $\wedge$) for example $[|x-y|>\frac12\vee|z-y|>\frac12]$.

So we assume that $[|x-y|>\frac12\vee|z-y|>\frac12]$, but in the proof I was shown they assumed that $[|x-y|>\frac12\wedge|z-y|>\frac12]$

Does that mean that the proof is wrong?

Comment: Maybe you're reading "at least two of the numbers" as meaning something like "at least two pairs of the numbers"?

Comment: Yes, my confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making some confusion. What you have to prove is that
$$\forall x,y,z ((0<x<y<z<1) \Rightarrow((|x-y| < 1/2) \vee (|x-z| < 1/2) \vee (|y-z| < 1/2))$$

So arguing by contradiction you have
$$\exists x,y,z  ((0<x<y<z<1) \wedge (|x-y| \ge 1/2) \wedge (|x-z| \ge 1/2) \wedge (|y-z| \ge 1/2) )$$
widh leads to the contradiction in the proof.

Comment: AH YES! Confused "at least two numbers.." with "at least two inequalities" lol